# Can't use Google Play app from Restricted Guest Account

Tags: google-play-store, permissions, restricted-profiles

I made a restricted guest account for others to use my device (Android 4.4.4. with CyanogenMod 11) and I am unallowed to give the account access to the Play Store. If I try and use the Play Store from the guest account it just says, "You have no permission." I can't find any way of allowing permission, as, from the settings for the guest account, the Play Store is not listed.

How can I allow the restricted account access to launch and use the Play Store app?

Answer (score 2):

From this [Google Product Forums Post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/_iVzWPBqzjw):

> "it is not possible to be able to grant access to the Play Store. You are however
>   able to grant access to the different Play apps like Books, Movies and Music. 
>   They will have access to the content you have."

So I'm sorry, but this is a product limitation. After all, why would you want a restricted user to be able to install apps? That sounds a bit purpose-defeating.

Comment: I'd like my restricted user to be able to use purchased IAP though.

Comment: @AaronMcMillin, as of yet, it isn't possible. New users have their own set of app data anyway, so they can't use any purchased IAPs.

Comment: :( Whelp now I own the City texture pack in Minecraft and my son can't use it.

Comment: @Aaron, If it hurts you that much, let your son play using your account :P

Answer (score 1):

It is a safety case. If you aren't **user 0** (not to be confused with UID 0, the root user) you can't access some certain stuff. Dev. Options for example, or as in your case, Google Play.